# WAMP Web Server Apache Will NOT Start

Tags: apache, wamp

My WAMP Apache server will not start on port 80, but does start on XAMPP. So it must be a problem with WAMP... I have changed very little, only httpd-vhosts.conf, and then I reverted those changes after it stopped working. I do not know what I did, or what WAMP messed up, but am looking for a solution to this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but you really expect people to be able to answer "I've done some stuff and other stuff deosn't work. Please help." ? Are you sure nothing else is running on port 80?

Comment: Do you still have XAMPP installed? Is the Apache that comes with XAMPP (which starts automatically) still starting automatically and therefore capturing port 80?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am expecting someone else to have the same issue. XAMPP is still installed but isn't running. I already said nothing is using port 80 but it still won't work. A solution would be beneficial to all that have this issue. I have given all the information I have about the issue.

Anyways, I don't know what was wrong with it but uninstalling and reinstalling WAMP fixed the issue, so it must have been an error with the program.